# Printing SD card file contents on LCD

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, lcd, sd-card

This is a part of my program which reads data from file stored in SD card and displays that on an LCD screen.

```C++
  File dataFile = SD.open("1165.txt");


  if (dataFile) {
    Serial.println("File Opened");
    lcd.clear();
       delay( 5 );  //LCD-specific M
       lcd.setCursor( 0,0 );


  while (dataFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(dataFile.read());
      lcd.write(dataFile.read());
      lcd.print(dataFile.read());
    }
  dataFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error");
  }
```

When I look at the serial monitor it prints the contents of that file but none of these commands print what is printed in the serial monitor,

```C++
lcd.write(dataFile.read());
lcd.print(dataFile.read());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `dataFile.read()`, the file pointer is advanced, so you always read different bytes in each `read` call. Imagine the file like a book with many lines: Each time you read, you advance the current line, so with multiple calls, you never get the same data. The solution is to currently store the last read byte:

```
while (dataFile.available()) {
  char readByte = dataFile.read();
  Serial.write(readByte);
  lcd.write(readByte);
  lcd.print(readByte);
}
```

You have two calls for displaying data in the LCD, but be careful that the second call (`print`) might interpret your data as a number, so just remove the `lcd.print(readByte)` call altogether to be sure it's printing the raw character.

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement a readLine routine, similar to:

```
void _readLine(File f, char *line)
{
    boolean cr_found = false;
    int p = 0;
    while (f.available()) {
        char b = f.read();
        if(b!='\r' && b!='\n')
            line[p++] = b;

        if(b == '\r') cr_found = true;
        if((b == '\n') && cr_found) break;
    }
    line[p] = '\0';
}
```

And read the SD file line by line, processing each one of them by its own.

```
char buffer[32];

while(dataFile.available()) {
    _readLine(dataFile, buffer);
    // do something with buffer
}
```